# Vue component prop undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

Sadly I'm not that familiar with Vue and hope someone can help me a bit...

I have this in my index.html:

```html
<xyz :isHidden="hidden">...</xyz>
```

Now, I have my xyz component:

```js
Vue.component('graph', {
  props: ['isHidden'],
  watch: {
    isHidden() {
     doSomething(this.isHidden);
    }, ...
  }
....
}
```

Then, I have my Vue app:

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  methods: {
    action() {
      this.hidden = !this.hidden;
    }, ...
  }, ....
  data: { hidden: false }
})
```

Now, as I understand the `:hidden="isHidden"` part should bind the two variable in the different part together, right? So when I change `isHidden` it should also change `hidden` and therefore call the watched function which does something. But as it turns out it doesn't.. already when my component is loaded `hidden` is undefined..

Did I forget something? Or is my mistake probably in the part "..." part of my code? .-.

Answer (score 1):

**data** section should be a function:

```
data () { 
  return {
    isHidden: false 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, wait.. now I feel stupid....

Well, anyone else struggling: **no big letters (camelCase) in Vue-HTML..**

fixed HTML:

```html
<xyz :is-hidden="hidden">...</xyz>
```

the rest can stay the same..

Comment: THIS! took me so long to figure out :) I thought its vue3 issue :D

Answer (score 0):

you forget use components prop and tag name and component name is should be same

```
 new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        'xyz': xyz,
      }
    })
```

component name

```
Vue.component('xyz', {
      props: ['hidden'],
      watch: {
        hidden() {
         doSomething(this.hidden);
        }, ...
      }
    ....
    }
```

this link should help you: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html